# Error in rendering form in livecycle process for first time

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

currently we changed environment for adobe server.

and now we are facing problem when i invoke service sometime.
it throws following error

```
com.adobe.livecycle.formsservice.exception.RenderFormException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection to failed service.
    at com.adobe.formServer.FormServer.renderForm(FormServer.java:234)
    at com.adobe.formServer.FormServer.renderForm(FormServer.java:282)
    at com.adobe.formServer.docservice.FormsDocService.renderForm(FormsDocService.java:556)
    at com.adobe.formServer.docservice.FormsDocService.renderForm(FormsDocService.java:470)
    at com.adobe.formServer.docservice.FormsDocService.renderPDFFormCommonCaller(FormsDocService.java:166)
    at com.adobe.formServer.docservice.FormsDocService.renderPDFForm2(FormsDocService.java:139)
```

but on second hit it work very well..
please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is reproduce because of PermSize issue.

To fix it  :-

Please set the -Xms256m -Xmx1792m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m in PATH.

Go to server console-->servers-->managedserver-->Server Start and set -Xms256m -Xmx1792m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m in Arguments.